# How compare strings of integers?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a question and I don't understand the problem!

When I compare 2 strings of integers, I haven't the right result:

```js
console.log('#178' < '#13406');
console.log('178' < '13406');
console.log('178' < '200');
```

I should have

```
True
True
True
```

How can I compare these strings without convert to integer ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why you think it's converted to integer? It's compared char by char, so in first '#1**7**' is bigger than '#1**3**', same with second '1**7**' and  '1**3**'. Last one is correct because it compares first symbol only from strings

Comment: *"without convert to integer"* - If you're just comparing them **as strings** then the results you're seeing are correct.  To compare the numeric text as numbers you'll need to convert them to numbers.  Why don't you want to convert them to numbers?

Comment: Ok thanks ! I should have to convert to integer then ! Thanks a lot it's clear

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse them as integer by removing al non number chars first.

```js
const parse = (s) => parseInt(s.replace(/\D+/g, ''));
console.log(parse('#178') < parse('#13406'));
console.log(parse('178') < parse('13406'));
console.log(parse('178') < parse('200'));
```